# Unable to find sub documents in mongodb by their id using findOne()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs, http-status-code-404, subdocument

Test cases to check status 200 and status 400 are failing. In both cases, I receive the status as 404, which means the rental doesn't exist in db.

```
const rental_exists = await RentalCollectionClass.findOne({
                                                    "customer._id" : req.body.customerId,
                                                    "movie._id" : req.body.movieId });
        if(!rental_exists) 
            return res.status(404).send('Rental with given customer/movie not in db'); 
        if(rental_exists.dateReturned)         
            return res.status(400).send('Rental with given customer/movie already processed');   
        return res.status(200).send('Valid rental posted');
```

But I have created the rental in beforeEach() function of the testcase as below.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        customerId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
        movieId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
        rental = new RentalCollectionClass({
            customer : {
                id : customerId,
                name : 'nandhini',
                phone : 12345
            },
            movie : {
                id : movieId,
                title : 'movieTitle',
            }
        });
        await rental.save();
    });
```

Also note that the customer & movie are sub documents of rental. Help me fix this please!!

Comment: could you console.log(req.body) ?

Comment: The values `req.body.customerId` and `req.body.movieId` are likely string in `req.body`, what data type are `customer._id` and `movie._id` in the database.

Comment: console.log
    {
      customerId: '615e8e8754d9091104058d9a',
      movieId: '615e8e8754d9091104058d9b'
    }